# async waterfall return single record of array in node js and mongodb

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I am creating chield and parent category menu in nodejs and mongodb and angularjs. My concern is when i returning the pushed array using callback the array contains only single record although i have alot of data.I dont know what is gonig wrong. here is my code.

```
async.waterfall([
  function(cb) {
    //getting the parent category
    mealCatModel.find({
      parentId: ''
    }, {}, function(error, result) {
      if (error) {
        cb(error, null);
      } else {
        if (result) {
          //loop through the record
          result.forEach(function(key, value) {
            //find the chield category on behalf of parent id and key.id
            mealCatModel.find({
              parentId: key._id
            }, {}, function(err, subCat) {
              if (subCat) {
                subCat.forEach(function(k, v) {
                  if (k.parentId == key._id) {
                    // pushing all the record in a single array
                    mainJson.push({
                      mainCatId: key._id,
                      mainCatName: key.mealCatName,
                      subCatId: k._id,
                      subCatName: k.mealCatName
                    });
                    cb(null, mainJson);

                  }
                })
              }
            })
          })
        } else {
          cb('record not foound', null);
        }
      }

    });
  }
], function(error, mainJson) {
  ///return the err
  if (error) {
    res.json({
      type: false,
      data: 0
    });
  } else {
    // return the array to front end
    res.json({
      type: true,
      data: mainJson
    });
  }
});
```

The first find function get the main category and depend on that record i am looping through in key value pairs and then i found key._id on behalf of that  i again run the find query which has id parent of main category. so in that way i get my chield category and then pushing the data in mainJson array. but when i return the cb() callback it return only single array.

Answer (score 0):

The callback is being executed in the `.forEach`. At the time of its execution, the loop hasn't completed all its iterations. You should refactor the code to return the callback after the `.forEach` expression:

```
if (subCat) {
  subCat.forEach(function(k, v) {
    if (k.parentId == key._id) {
      // pushing all the record in a single array
      mainJson.push({
        mainCatId: key._id,
        mainCatName: key.mealCatName,
        subCatId: k._id,
        subCatName: k.mealCatName
      });
    }
  });
  return cb(null, mainJson);
}
```